# What methods should I be using in a Django class-based view IPNs?

Tags: django, paypal

For example: `dispatch()`, `get_template_name()` and `get_context_data()`.

I'm trying to setup PayPal IPN, which has great PHP documentation, but there's not much available around the web for Django. I almost have it working. I can use the IPN simulator successfully. I am just wondering, what method should I put my *actions* under? Like the actions of capturing the POST variables, sending them back and getting them verified from PayPal then taking action on the order? Right now, I have that all under `get_context_data` which seems to make PayPal's IPN simulator alert "IPN sent successfully", but it doesn't seem to create users or do the other actions I have specified in that method. I have 2 functions in my class-based view: `dispatch()` which returns 200 OK and `get_context_data()` which handles everything else.

So basically, what methods do you use in your class-based view for your IPNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) method is used to fetch the data which is used to render the template. It shouldn't really be creating users or carrying out other actions.

You can override `dispatch()`, but a more common approach would be to override `get()` or `post()` depending on whichever request type you are dealing with. The base implementation of `dispatch()` calls the appropriate method depending on the request type (e.g. `get()` or `post()`)

If you are validating POST variables, then you should consider using Django [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), and subclassing the [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview).

[Classy Class-Based Views](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is a good resource for exploring the methods or class based views.

Finally, you don't have to use a class based view, there's nothing wrong with using a function based view if you're happier structuring your code that way.